# Hibernate doesn't work when another hard drive is plugged in

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, hibernate

I recently took a good 512GB NVMe SSD out of a bad laptop. I wanted to use it as my game drive, so I wiped the hard drive and reformatted it with disk managment.

I was having issues with the computer booting up, but went into the BIOS and changed the boot priority settings, and disabled boot from the new drive. The issue I can't seem to fix is when I set the computer to hibernate. The computer will shut down, but when I power it back up, I get the motherboard splash screen, windows will start to load for about 2 seconds, and then it will reset itself. After the reset, the computer will start up properly but doesn't load the previous hibernate state.

This problem only occurs when I have the new hard drive plugged in. When I remove the hard drive from the PC, and try to hibernate, it works correctly.

### Edit: Event Viewer Data Added After a failed Hibernate

- A problem has occurred with one or more user-mode drivers and the hosting process has been terminated.  This may temporarily interrupt your ability to access the devices.
- Volume Shadow Copy Service information: The COM Server with CLSID {4e14fba2-2e22-11d1-9964-00c04fbbb345} and name CEventSystem cannot be started. [0x8007045b, A system shutdown is in progress.
  ]
- The RasMan service depends on the SstpSvc service which failed to start because of the following error:
  The operation completed successfully.
- A timeout (30000 milliseconds) was reached while waiting for a transaction response from the NcdAutoSetup service.
- The Gaming Services service terminated with the following error:
  This operation returned because the timeout period expired.
- Volume Shadow Copy Service error: Unexpected error calling routine CoCreateInstance.  hr = 0x8007045b, A system shutdown is in progress.
- The server DolbyLaboratories.DolbyAccess_3.7.337.0_x64__rz1tebttyb220!App.AppXtzbhf6k67jn9be72jwc3zje4rv3bb4am.mca did not register with DCOM within the required timeout.

Comment: If you can find pertinent information in the Event Viewer, please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1614130/edit) it into the post.

Comment: @harrymc I have added the Event Viewer data that appears after a failed hibernate

Comment: Very confusing general failure. I suggest running `chkdsk`, [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html) (and the included DISM command) and to verify the SMART data of all disks. I also hope that your PSU has enough juice for the additional disk.